# How to manage classpath in eclipse for one project and two build targets

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, dependency-management

I have Java application project in eclipse. This project contains the one abstract class and two implementations+GUI. In haves two classes with main methods that launches GUI with one of the implementations. 
Each implementation uses some set of unique jar libraries, another set is of same libs (shared). 
Is there any way to compile and build first implementation with one set of jars in classpath, another implementation - another set of libs inside one project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant do in eclipse runtime, in single project
 i suggest to use [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) for build, using this you can make jar or compile-deploy with your specific jar set